# LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding, kotlin

I am using [this](https://github.com/skedgo/DateTimeRangePicker) library and have enabled `dataBinding` and is using `kapt-android` plugin. Following error comes up when I build the project:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException:
Found data binding errors.
```

app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//For green dao
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/greendao'
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.skedgo:DateTimeRangePicker:v1.3'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    ...
}
greendao {
    targetGenDir 'src/main/java'
}
}
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

What can be the possible cause?

Comment: Check this issue thread. It may helps you: https://github.com/skedgo/DateTimeRangePicker/issues/14

Comment: @pRaNaY Still issue is not solved.